# Gesture detector not working

Tags: android

I want to swipe from one activity to another without using Viewpager and i want to use only SwipeGesture i have written the code but my screen is not sliding so anyone can tell me whats wrong with the code ? here is my code:

```
public class Ashtakoota extends AbstractActivity implements IAPICallback,View.OnClickListener {


private LinearLayout lnrAsht;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_ashtakoota,mFrameLayout);


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    lnrAsht = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnrAsht);

    mbtnBack = (FancyButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_match_ashtakootback);
    mbtnNext =(FancyButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_match_ashtakootnext);

    mbtnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    mbtnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    lnrAsht.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };




    mHandler = new ViewHandler();
    callAPI();





}



private class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(Ashtakoota.this, "Gesture Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
            float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

            if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            // Left swipe
            if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                onLeftSwipe();
            }
            // Right swipe
            else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                onRightSwipe();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Home", "Error on gestures");
        }
        return false;
    }


}

private void onLeftSwipe() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,BasicAstro.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void onRightSwipe() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MatchManglik.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_match_ashtakootback:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,BasicAstro.class);
            startActivity(intent);}break;

        case R.id.btn_match_ashtakootnext:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MatchManglik.class);
            startActivity(intent);}break;
    }
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You set the gesture listener before initialising it.

Try this:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};

lnrAsht.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Comment: @agunal can you help ?

Comment: @Mirek Rusin can you help ?

Comment: @Anton Kizema can you help ?